# How to create a base class for controls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, inheritance

I have a base library that defines a user control

**BaseLib.dll:**

UC.xaml.cs

```
<UserControl x:Class="BaseLib.UC" ...
```

UC.xaml.cs

```
public abstract partial class UC : UserControl, IFoo
{
    public UC()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected abstract Foo();
}
```

Then, different libraries can inherit from the control and overload the methods. They only implement abstract methods, and do nothing to the underlying XAML

**Lib2.dll**

```
public class NewControl : UC
{
    protected override Foo(){ /* do stuff*/}
}
```

The base lib compiles just fine, and so do the derived classes. But, when I try to create an instance of the derived controls, I get this error on InitializeComponent() in the UC constructor:

```
System.Exception: 'The component 'NewControl' does not have a resource identified by the URI '/BaseLib;component/UC.xaml'.'
```

Is this something I could fix with pack URI somewhere to point to the baselib xaml? I don't know where I would put it. I've looked at similar questions, but they don't exactly fit my intention. I'm not trying to inherit WPF elements and change their appearance or layout

Comment: I think you want to call the class directly by using its tag `<namespace:NewControl></namespace:NewControl>` which is a usercontrol.

Comment: What's in the `UC.xaml` file? An abstract base class should not have a partial XAML class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a base class that extends `UserControl`, you must follow a few rules.

- The base type must not be a `partial class` (have a XAML file).
- Since the base class is not allowed to have a partial XAML class definition, the base class must not call `InitializeComponent()`.
- The derived non abstract type that extends the base class must be a `partial class` that has a XAML class definition.
- The XAML root element of this derived control must be the base class.

If you want to reuse the actual view (the XAML definition) you must define it as a resource e.g. as a `ControlTemplate`.

The recommended approach is to extend `ContentControl` instead of `UserControl` (see second example below). This approach has no limitations compared to extending `UserControl`. It is very straight forward especially if you want to extend features without overriding the default appearance.

### Solution 1: Creating a base class using `UserControl` as superclass (not recommended)

**BaseUserControl.cs**
The abstract base class to be used in libraries.

```cs
public abstract class BaseUserControl : UserControl, IFoo
{
  protected abstract void Foo();
}
```

**App.xaml**
The `BaseUserControlTemplate` definition.

```xml
<Application.Resources>
  <ControlTemplate x:Key="BaseUserControlTemplate" 
                   TargetType="BaseUserControl">
    <TextBlock Text="Reusable view from template" />
  </ControlTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

**Library1UserControl.xaml.cs**
A custom library implementation of `BaseUserControl`.

```cs
public partial class Library1UserControl : BaseUserControl
{
  public Library1UserControl()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  protected override void Foo()
  {}
}
```

**Library1UserControl.xaml.cs**
The view definition of the `Library1UserControl` which reuses the predefined (e.g., in *App.xaml*) `BaseControlTemplate`.

```xml
<BaseControl x:Class="Library1UserControl"
             Template="{StaticResource BaseUserControlTemplate}" />
```

---

### Solution 2: Creating a base class using `ContentControl` or `Control` as superclass (recommended)

In case you want to explicitly define the view as part of the base class, then let your base class extent `ContentControl` (or `Control`) and define the default `Style` in the *Generic.xaml* resources (the *Generic.xaml* file is located in the Themes folder of the control library).
This way, all derived classes will automatically inherit the default view (unless they explicitly override the default `Style`).
Extending `ContentControl` or `Control` is generally the recommended approach over using `UserControl`.
You should consider to extend `ContentControl` instead of `UserControl`.

**BaseControl.cs**

```cs
public abstract class BaseControl : Control, IFoo
{
  static BaseControl()
  {    
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(BaseControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(BaseControl)));
  }

  protected abstract void Foo();
}
```

**Generic.xaml**
The *Generic.xaml* file is located in the *Themes* folder of the control library.

```xml
<ResourceDictionary>
  <Style TargetType="BaseControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="BaseControl">          
          <TextBlock Text="Reusable view from template" />
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**Library1Control.cs**
The derived type automatically inherits the default `Style` (and `ControlTemplate`)  that was defined in the base type.

```cs
public class Library1Control : BaseControl
{
  public Library1Control()
  {}

  protected override void Foo()
  {}
}
```

Comment: I don't like it but I suppose I was breaking rules :) I'll accept that answer. My UI changes are so null so I'll probably just pass implementation I want as a class a constructor argument.

Comment: There are many ways to extend the functionality of a class. Composition is one. Just note that the XAML engine requires a default constructor in case the control is added in XAML (e.g. via a DataTemplate). Using constructor injection for UI controls can be problematic, especially when the controls are part of a library. Creating an attached behavior can also provide a powerful alternative to inheritance or composition.

Comment: Is this what you're referring to? https://www.wpf-controls.com/behaviors-and-attached-properties/

Comment: Yes. It's an attached property that usually implements a feature (behavior) based on the element it is attached to. You can observe the element by handling its events. If this is a useful solution depends on what kind of feature you like your control to extend with, of course.

Comment: OK, I've gone through a bit of documentation and that's definitely something new and interesting to learn. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So I did a similar project structure to test.  This works fine.  The line `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PoopToTest"` would reference your BaseLib.dll namespace.

```
<Window
    x:Class="PoopToTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PoopToTest"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="800"
    Height="450"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <local:ActualControl>
            <TextBlock
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                FontSize="50"
                Text="Hello" />
        </local:ActualControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The base class.

```
namespace PoopToTest
{
    public abstract class BaseControl : UserControl
    {
        public BaseControl()
        {
            //InitializeComponent() is not in UserControl.  Needed a place to break.
            int x = int.MaxValue;
        }

        protected abstract void Foo();
    }
}
```

Implementation.

```
namespace PoopToTest
{
    public class ActualControl : BaseControl
    {
        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Foo()
        {
            //Do Stuff.
        }
    }
}
```